# How to change a file with a replaced output?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to write a function that takes the name of a file as a string, that opens, reads, and then writes a new file that changes each 4 letter word in the file with "XXXX".

So far I have:

```
def change(filename):
    infile = open(filename,'r')
    outfile = open('changed.txt', 'w')
    l = infile.read()
    infile.close()
    x = l.split()

    for word in x:
        if len(word) == 4:
            outfile.replace(word,'XXX')
```

I think that I'm messing up the output within my if statement, but I'm not sure how to fix this.

In my file (which I have called 'example.txt') I have :" this file contains three four letter words"

in my output file "changed.txt" I should get: "XXXX XXXX contains three XXXX letter words"

Comment: You shouldn't be closing `infile()` before reading it.

Comment: `infile` and `outfile` are file objects; you need to read from one and write data to the other. `.replace()` and `.split()` are string methods, so those won't work on files.

Comment: @TimPietzcker I edited it by adding l = infile.read() to read before closing the file. is this correct?

Comment: Not quite, after all, you still need to write something to `outfile`, and you have removed all information on spaces and newlines from your data. One question before I post a suggestion: Do you consider `they` within `they're` a four-letter word?

Comment: no, I do not consider they within they're. For now, I want to keep it simple, untill I can fully understand since I'm new to python

Comment: OK, then you need to define exactly what you mean by "word". Anything surrounded by whitespace? Should "He said yes!" become "He XXXX XXXX"?

Comment: each word for the purpose of this function, I consider a word to be a single distinct element in English while excluding contractions or any words with an apostrophe. I want to keep sentences simple such that they do not contain symbols, numeric characters, or anything that isn't created by characters in the alphabet A-Z.

Comment: I wouldnt consider the word "yes!" in your sentence because the fourth character is an exclamation mark so instad it should be. "He XXXX yes!"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One suggestion how to achieve what you're trying to do:

```
import re
def change(filename):
    with open(filename) as infile, open("changed.txt", "w") as outfile:
        text = infile.read()
        outfile.write(re.sub(r"\b\w{4}\b", "XXXX", text))
```

This assumes (as a simplification) that a "word" is a sequence of four alphanumeric characters, surrounded by non-alphanumeric characters. If that is not specific enough (it would also match `2001`, would not match `böse` and would change `they're` to `XXXX're`), let me know.

The main work is done by the regex `\b\w{4}\b` which means "match a [word boundary](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html), then four alphanumeric characters, then a word boundary".

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
re.sub('([^\w]|^)\w{4}(?=[^\w]|$)', r'\1XXXX', input)
```

should do the trick.

EDIT: right separator is lookahead

Comment: This fails if two four-letter words follow each other.

Comment: Why not use `\b` word boundaries instead? They implement exactly this functionality.

Comment: did not come to mind. :) - wanted to preserve the answer. Especially after defining a set of boundary characters, this is easier to adapt.